# I want to upload video on amazon cloud using REST api

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, api, rest, webrequest

I have shared Documentation to upload file from this [link](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/nodes).

**Upload File**

Uploads the file content along with its metadata information.

POST : {{contentUrl}}/nodes?suppress={suppress}

suppress : (Optional)

deduplication: disables checking for duplicates when uploading Body Parameters:

Multi-form part

--------- metadata ------------

name (required) : file name. Max to 256 Characters.  kind (required) : "FILE"  labels (optional) : Extra information which is indexed. For example the value can be "PHOTO"  properties (optional) : List of properties to be added for the file.  parents(optional) : List of parent Ids. If no parent folders are provided, the file will be placed in the default root folder.
---------content ------------

File Bytes

**Sample Request:**

```
     POST /cdproxy/nodes?localId=testPhoto
     HTTP/1.1
     Host: content-na.drive.amazonaws.com
     Authorization: Bearer
     Atza|IQEBLjAsAhReYeezFcFdYzqrFOJGv3EG

   ----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"

   {"name":"fooo.jpg","kind":"FILE"}
   ----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content";
   filename="db5df4870e4e4b6cbf42727fd434701a.jpg"
   Content-Type: image/jpeg

   ----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
   **cURL Request:**
   curl -v -X POST --form
  'metadata={"name":"testVideo1","kind":"FILE"}' --form
  'content=@sample_iTunes.mp4'
  'https://content-na.drive.amazonaws.com/cdproxy/nodes?localId=testVideo1&suppress=deduplication'
   --header "Authorization: Bearer
   Atza|IQEBLjAsAhQ5zx7pKp9PCgCy6T1JkQjHHOEzpwIUQM"
```

Fiddler:
I have written code and sent request.
This is the request i have sent using Fiddler

> POST
> https://content-na.drive.amazonaws.com/cdproxy//nodes?suppress=deduplication
> HTTP/1.1 Authorization: Bearer
> Atza|IQEBLjAsAhQXfR4gxrstIKB8jjCbbsTIRhad1QIUZgLJFXgenPSsYLp6VHeL2rEBQ6RFSQYAR847Pvr8bnF4wc-qAlP2oKbAxogI_KJBopMzbTwt3n1DgJ9D8VJTikjdkXH7_595n4ElGhAhKJybhiXBlZLDh7ScXiFC6g4MFfkVRMKoKWAf4gRhhYGTLX2nBSHWIYx5kpzbS0QNgOUS_Hluodfq0j5gf8FeNB3YG6q-KiQMdPbcXJFlKs28f_cSWnQvYyLu0c8YzcJZpjL3CTrabnGpF5KOM6ie71Q2mS3ncL71tEO5wu3MVEJZZtg00MKM5nkGAzH1hCHqA0PWmsLsQVm0X684Seje7aSMYDlh0hcRpgc4Y7fusEndnprz5EO9FftNDN3lbvxszgAR0DhoOg
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data Host: content-na.drive.amazonaws.com
> Content-Length: 2100825 Expect: 100-continue
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundary8d2ff0fafd6a750 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"
>
> {"name":"C:\Users\jafar.baltidynamolog\Downloads\SampleVideo_360x240_2mb.mp4","kind":"FILE"}
> ------WebKitFormBoundary8d2ff0fafd6a750 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content";
> filename="C:\Users\jafar.baltidynamolog\Downloads\SampleVideo_360x240_2mb.mp4" Content-Type: video/mp4
>
> ��� ftypisom���isomiso2avc1mp41���free��LmdatT Lj����L5
>
> ��P�L"�:�ԮoU*Nx��V���qFM4��w�ח�l�iݧ����o��͑s����z���/e��ۢ�a���G��y�j�W-&{x�w��>�I���6�v�u�j;��pk#�=�K�ZO.a�yy
> -w(���ژ�#S�Rpt<{�ڿZ38xt���x�[��ɒ�&�lsT��4P��rMXv��Ѹ%A�5���C�hH&   ���P�   Z���翷�n�����z���5t��D��M%�}���i���P|�k��#�>�#�tq�O�K���sy��=�\��9���)���Ɏ�������*�T��(��=v����
> )D���R;zKBx��PU� ���E�/bB��)p�h,6��`��� ���XH2

Problem is that I am getting Error 500 internal Error. Kindly help me understand if some thing is missing or wrong. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2996904/2409701) code to upload video.